# Not printing the txt file after program ends

Tags: python

It is opening an txt file and writes what is asked. But does not print the results on the first time.
When I run the program again, then the results that were stored in the txt file from the first run get printed.

Why does it nog print the results from the first run on the first run.

Just starting out.

import random

```
print("======WELCOME TO THE DICE GUESSING GAME=======")
print("Rules of the game : - You can try 3 times!")
print("")
dice = random.randint(1, 6)
guesses = 3`enter code here`
file = open("score.txt", "a")
file.write("Dice number: " + str(dice) + " ")
while guesses > 0:
    guess = int(input("guess the number of the dice: "))
    file.write("guess = " + str(guess) + " ")
    if dice == guess:
        print("That is the correct answer!")
        print("You have won the game!")
        break
    elif guesses != 1:
        print("Try again! You have " + str(guesses - 1) + " chances left, good luck! ")
        guesses -= 1
    else:
        print("You did not guess the correct number!")
        print("The correct number was: " + str(dice))
        break
content = open("score.txt", "r")
read = content.read()
print(read)
file.close()
```

Comment: Close the file after everything is written, before opening it again for reading.

Comment: Not sure what your exact problem is as you are too vague. However an issue you may be facing is that you `file=open("score.txt", "a")` and never close it prior to opening the same file again. Also when opening in append the file pointer may be at the end. So when opening it again there may not be any content to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `file` handle before reading the file back in from the `content` handle, as file output is buffered.

Here is what the code should look like after the while loop:

```py
file.close()
content = open("score.txt", "r")
read = content.read()
print(read)
content.close()
```